# Proof of $(u.v)=(u_{x}.v_{x}+u_{y}.v_{y}+u_{z}.v_{z})$, assuming $(u.v)=|u||v|cos\theta$.

Tags: vector-spaces

I would really love any sort of proof of this.

I have a very elementary geometric proof for $R^{2}$. That's mainly because I can easily represent $cos\theta$ in the form of $\frac{u_{x}v_{x}+u_{y}v_{y}}{\sqrt{(u_{x}^{2}+u_{y}^{2})(v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2})}}$.

I don't know a way of representing $cos\theta$ in $R^{3}$ without using dot product.

Comment: Make a triangle with sides $||\vec u||$, $||\vec v||$ and $||\vec u-\vec v||$ (Find out why this is possible). Apply the cosine rule in this triangle and then rewrite the expression $||\vec u||\cdot||\vec v||\cdot\cos\theta$

Comment: I've seen the above proof. The assumption that $(u.u)=|u|^{2}$ is necessary here. I don't want to make this assumption.

Comment: That isn't an assumption because $\theta$ is **defined** to be the angle between $u$ and $v$ and so the cosine of the angle between $u$ and $u$ is $1$.

Comment: By barto's method, I'm getting $(u-v).(u-v)=(u.u)+(v.v)-2(u.v)$. One possibility is that the LHS has been expanded to get the RHS. But how do we know this is the ONLY possibility?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you asking whether I could somehow expand the LHS to something different (in the sense that it is not equivalent) to the current expansion? At each step of expanding the LHS it should be an "if and only if". Unless, you're doing something wrong you'll end up with something that isn't equivalent to your expansion. Please explain if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP still seems to have some doubt, I've put together a community wiki answer based on the suggestions made in comments.

Make the definition
$$u\cdot v:=\Vert u\Vert\Vert v\Vert\cos\theta,$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v.$  Then $u\cdot u=\Vert u\Vert\Vert u\Vert\cos0=\Vert u\Vert^2=u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2,$
where the last equality follows from the Pythagorean Theorem.

Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
(u-v)\cdot(u-v)&=(u_x-v_x)^2+(u_y-v_y)^2+(u_z-v_z)^2\\
&=(u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2)+(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)-2(u_xv_x+u_yv_y+u_zv_z)\\
&=u\cdot u+v\cdot v-2(u_xv_x+u_yv_y+u_zv_z).
\end{aligned}
$$
On the other hand
$$
\begin{aligned}
(u-v)\cdot(u-v)&=\Vert u-v\Vert^2\\
&=\Vert u\Vert^2+\Vert v\Vert^2-2\Vert u\Vert\Vert v\Vert\cos\theta\\
&=u\cdot u+v\cdot v-2u\cdot v,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the law of cosines was used to obtain line $2.$  Comparing these expressions gives the result.